# Register function for JWT gives me a different json error in Laravel. How to write the register function?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, postman

These are register and login functions and **api.php** for routing. Register and login are in **AuthController**. When I do post request through **Postman** for register I am getting this error. Is there any error in the code or should I review my headers in Postman?

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
    ]);

    $token = $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}

 public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
}
```

Here is my **routes/api.php** file.

```
Route::group([

'middleware' => 'api',
'prefix' => 'auth'
```

], function ($router) {

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');
```

});

Comment: can you attach `routes/api.php` and `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`?

Comment: I did. I think the problem is not related to routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. The problem was the **__construct()** function in **AuthController.php**
There was just login routing in the middleware. When I added register also, it worked.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use this [jwt-auth](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/quick-start/#authenticated-requests)

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

  class AuthController extends Controller
  {
/**
 * Create a new AuthController instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
}

/**
 * Get a JWT token via given credentials.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($token = $this->guard('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
}

/**
 * Get the authenticated User
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function me()
{
    return response()->json($this->guard('api')->user());
}

/**
 * Log the user out (Invalidate the token)
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function logout()
{
    $this->guard('api')->logout();

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
}

/**
 * Refresh a token.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function refresh()
{
    return $this->respondWithToken($this->guard('api')->refresh());
}

/**
 * Get the token array structure.
 *
 * @param  string $token
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
protected function respondWithToken($token)
{
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'bearer',
        'expires_in' => $this->guard('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 60
    ]);
}

/**
 * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard
 */
public function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('api');
}
}
```

And this controller is works for me. Notice that I replace `guard()` to `guard('api')`

Comment: but if you didn't follow this https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/quick-start/#authenticated-requests it may not works xD

Comment: but my problem is about register function and there is no register in the above code. the rest works very well.

Comment: the `function respondWithToken($token)` is used to register the user